# Error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: connect: connection refused when starting Redis container without Docker Compose

Tags: docker, go, redis

I tried running a Redis container with the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder

LABEL maintainer="..."

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

COPY --from=builder /app/main .

EXPOSE 6379

CMD ["./main"]
```

Then, I ran

```
docker build -t redis .
docker run -dp 6379:6379 redis
```

Afterwards, there is an error on this side of the code:

```
    s.Client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })

    if err := s.Client.Ping().Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create a Redis client: %s", err)
    }
```

I have read some similar questions in Stackoverflow and tried changing the address to `redis:6379`, but it didn't work. Could someone help me explain why there is this connection refused error?

Some questions I've read:

- [Docker Redis Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360356/docker-redis-connection-refused)
- [Go backend to redis connection refused after docker compose up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951731/go-backend-to-redis-connection-refused-after-docker-compose-up)

Comment: `localhost` almost always means "the current container" in Docker.  Since you're manually `docker run`ning the containers without Compose, they need to be on the same `docker run --network`; the "how to communicate" question linked above describes this setup.  You'd then use the `docker run --name` of the Redis container as a host name.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the explanation! I simply forgot that I need a Redis container running first before I can run my Go code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You image is based on alpine, not on redis image. And I can't see where do you install redis in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Oh right. I need to use Docker Compose to up my Redis container first, then run this Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, first start your redis (either with docker compose or like "docker run -d redis". You should consider proper networking (both containers should be in one network in order to communicate) and correct url of redis insead of localhost:6379.

Comment: It worked already. I used docker compose. I can't believe I missed such a silly thing. Thanks!